# Controlling a LED on a Raspberry Pi 3 with PHP

Tags: raspbian, rpi.gpio, windows-iot

I want to control a LED using PHP on a Raspberry Pi 3 via web page.  I have installed Raspbian on RPi 3. I have installed apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5 and the wiring Pi library. I can access my web page from another computer.

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
 <title>LED Control</title>
 </head>
         <body>
         LED Control:
         <form method="get" action="gpio.php">
                 <input type="submit" value="ON" name="on">
                 <input type="submit" value="OFF" name="off">
         </form>
         <?php
         $setmode17 = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g mode 17 out");
         if(isset($_GET['on'])){
                 $gpio_on = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g write 17 1");
                 echo "LED is on";
         }
         else if(isset($_GET['off'])){
                 $gpio_off = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g write 17 0");
                 echo "LED is off";
         }
         ?>
         </body>
</html>
```

I am getting this error "http 500 error" What could be wrong ? Do you see any mistake in my code? What could be the issues ?

Comment: If you are getting a 500 error, the very first diagnostic step is to examine your server error log to see if there is any information that might point to the source of the problem.

Comment: if I put this  <?php echo "hello world"; ?> I don't  get any error but when I try with code in question then I get 500 error

Comment: Is this helpful [StackOverflow: Execute a shell script in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882650/how-to-execute-a-shell-script-in-php)

Comment: PHP is probably the wrong tool for this, in addition to whatever specific problem you're having here.  PHP runs when the page *loads*. You usually want this sort of action to happen when the user takes action - in your case clicks a button - from a page that *already loaded*.

Comment: Your code works fine for me if I divide it into two files with the form as `test.html` and the php script as `gpio.php` as you've named already...  Default installation of `apache2` and `libapache2-mod-php` on Raspbian Stretch installed on a RPi Zero.

Comment: There is  problem of ownership. When I check file it show permission denied.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read your server error log as larsks say. However, you can avoid having to make system calls. I leave you a link to a library to be able to use the LEDs directly with fwrite() functions instead of shell_exec(). I hope it can serve you: https://github.com/vivesweb/led_raspberry

Comment: Could you please indicate if you are the author of the library?